# Monogame Content Load Exception

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

Made a game in Monogame, but when I run it I get a ton of output saying there are a bunch of DLLs missing. The game runs fine in the sense that it doesn't crash, but I'll freeze for a second when I get one of these errors. It usually happens when I load an asset, but won't happen again when that asset is already loaded.

Here's the output from a single run.

```
'Rougelike.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'. Symbols loaded.

'Rougelike.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'D:\Dropbox\Projects\GurmLibX\Rougelike\bin\Windows\Release\Rougelike.exe'. Symbols loaded.

'Rougelike.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Rougelike.exe): Loaded 'D:\Dropbox\Projects\GurmLibX\Rougelike\bin\Windows\Release\GurmLibX.dll'. Symbols loaded.

'Rougelike.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Rougelike.exe): Loaded 'D:\Dropbox\Projects\GurmLibX\Rougelike\bin\Windows\Release\MonoGame.Framework.dll'. Module was built without symbols.

'Rougelike.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Rougelike.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.dll'. Symbols loaded.

'Rougelike.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Rougelike.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'. Symbols loaded.

'Rougelike.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Rougelike.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll'. Symbols loaded.

'Rougelike.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Rougelike.exe): Loaded 'D:\Dropbox\Projects\GurmLibX\Rougelike\bin\Windows\Release\SharpDX.RawInput.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'Rougelike.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Rougelike.exe): Loaded 'D:\Dropbox\Projects\GurmLibX\Rougelike\bin\Windows\Release\SharpDX.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'Rougelike.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Rougelike.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll'. Symbols loaded.

'Rougelike.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Rougelike.exe): Loaded 'D:\Dropbox\Projects\GurmLibX\Rougelike\bin\Windows\Release\SharpDX.Direct3D11.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'Rougelike.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Rougelike.exe): Loaded 'D:\Dropbox\Projects\GurmLibX\Rougelike\bin\Windows\Release\SharpDX.DXGI.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in mscorlib.dll

Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.ContentLoadException' in MonoGame.Framework.dll

'Rougelike.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Rougelike.exe): Loaded 'D:\Dropbox\Projects\GurmLibX\Rougelike\bin\Windows\Release\SharpDX.Direct2D1.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in mscorlib.dll

Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.ContentLoadException' in MonoGame.Framework.dll

Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in mscorlib.dll

Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.ContentLoadException' in MonoGame.Framework.dll

Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in mscorlib.dll

Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.ContentLoadException' in MonoGame.Framework.dll

Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in mscorlib.dll

Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.ContentLoadException' in MonoGame.Framework.dll

Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in mscorlib.dll

Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.ContentLoadException' in MonoGame.Framework.dll

Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in mscorlib.dll

Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.ContentLoadException' in MonoGame.Framework.dll

Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in mscorlib.dll

Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.ContentLoadException' in MonoGame.Framework.dll

Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in mscorlib.dll

Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.ContentLoadException' in MonoGame.Framework.dll

'Rougelike.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Rougelike.exe): Loaded 'D:\Dropbox\Projects\GurmLibX\Rougelike\bin\Windows\Release\SharpDX.XInput.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in mscorlib.dll

Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.ContentLoadException' in MonoGame.Framework.dll

'Rougelike.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Rougelike.exe): Loaded 'D:\Dropbox\Projects\GurmLibX\Rougelike\bin\Windows\Release\SharpDX.XAudio2.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

The program '[21932] Rougelike.exe: Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[21932] Rougelike.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
```

This is the code I use to load assets:

GurmLibX.Framework.GameGLX.cs : Game

```
Core.Content.Manager = Content;
```

GurmLibX.Framework.Content.cs

```
public static ContentManager Manager = null;

public static string RootDirectory
{
    get { return Manager.RootDirectory; }
    set { Manager.RootDirectory = value; }
}

public static T Load<T>(string assetName)
{
    return Manager.Load<T>(assetName);
}
```

Which is used like:

```
SpriteFont font = Content.Load<SpriteFont>("fonts/someFont");
```

Any guesses as to why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

First let's take a look at the errors.

> 'Rougelike.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Rougelike.exe): Loaded 'D:\Dropbox\Projects\GurmLibX\Rougelike\bin\Windows\Release\SharpDX.DXGI.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

I believe these "Cannot find or open the PDB file" errors are nothing to worry about. PDB files are used when debugging in Visual Studio so it could be slightly annoying that you can't step into code contained within these DLLs but other than that it shouldn't affect your game.

> Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in mscorlib.dll
>
> Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.ContentLoadException' in MonoGame.Framework.dll

I think these two are closely related. I believe the first exception is triggering the second exception deep within the bowels of MonoGame.

Essentially when the `Content.Load` method is trying to load your content files they can't be found.

```
SpriteFont font = Content.Load<SpriteFont>("fonts/someFont");
```

What usually happens is that the content is processed by [MonoGame's Content Pipeline tool](http://www.monogame.net/documentation/?page=Pipeline) at build time and the content files are output to a Content folder next to your executable.

The exact path to your folder varies depending on the setup but in your case (based on the error messages) it should be something like:

```
D:\Dropbox\Projects\GurmLibX\Rougelike\bin\Windows\Release\Content
```

Have a look in that folder and see if you can find the XNB files generated by the Pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using VS 2017? You may experience some issues, in my case, I launched the  MonoGame's Content Pipeline tool stand alone and built all the Content folder Add **Existing Item > (Your Sprite) > Build**. May not be the best solution but it can let you work ;)